# image upload using MultipartEntity class in android

Tags: android

i have to upload image file and send it to server ,so i m using MultipartEntity  class it giving me following error message..

```
Multiple markers at this line

- MultipartEntity cannot be resolved to a type
- The type new RecoverySystem.ProgressListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
 RecoverySystem.ProgressListener.onProgress(int)
- MultipartEntity cannot be resolved to a type
```

here is the code

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://politician.qkzoom.com");
        return responseString;



        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(new ProgressListener() {

            public void transferred(long num) {

                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you write full class name of MultipartEntity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload image by convert it to Base64 String and send the string to server then decode Base64 String in server side to get the image 
this code will convert image to Base64 String

```
public static final String convertImageToBase64(Bitmap bm) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); // bm is the bitmap
                                                            // object
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();

        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

this is the imports you wont to use

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Base64;
```